# Date column sort is not working in Primeng <p-table>

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a table using Primeng  for displaying the table values.
In the table there is one column for date, for date the sort option is not working. 
It is considering as normal string value instead of Date.

From the service getting the date in timestamp format. Using below code in UI to convert the date in required format.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
}



dateFormat(val: any) {
    if (val.toString().indexOf('.') > 0) {
      return this.datePipe.transform(new Date(val * 1000), 'd-MMM-y');
    } else {
      val = val.toString() + '.0000';
      return this.datePipe.transform(new Date(val * 1000), 'd-MMM-y');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can set one field for display date

```
this.data.forEach(ds => {
      ds.display_year = this.dateFormat(ds.year);
});
```

But sort on real field (`date` type)

This is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ismfn)

Comment: Thanks @phucnh, In the demo Date column values are in timestamp format but in my code the Date column values are in string format  like ''24-Jan-2018"

Comment: What's your response type?

Comment: Response type is Json

Comment: It is solved used <p-table> custom sorting given in Primeng documentation. Converted the Date typefrom string to Date type it worked

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using datepipe in 's column: `{{your_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`